# Eliminate render blocking javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to improve the performance of a web page on mobile devices by eliminating render blocking javascript from above the fold content as advised by google page speed insights. All the javascript files the page uses are for a text box towards the top of the page where users select ingredients :

jquery-1.8.2.js, textext.js, home.js

I tried moving all these files to the end of the html, but it caused the textbox to break. I also tried using the async attribute for the scripts but this had the same effect. Is there any way I can fix this problem? The page is [here](http://recipesuggester.co.uk/index.htm).

Comment: How did it break? Do you have a link to the version with the scripts at the bottom?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide a link to that, but basically it stopped the textbox from working and even crashed the page in my browser.

Comment: Ah, I swapped around the position of the home.js and textext.js files at the end of the html and that seemed to solve the problem with the textbox breaking / page crashing. But have I eliminated the render blocking javascript from above the fold content properly, or is there a better way I should have done it ?

Comment: Sounds like you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible direction can be finding the specific blocking functions (for example, `alert`). Then overriding those with non-blocking ones, by implementing them before the current code is executed.

For example, you can implement `alert` as a modal, allowing the rendering to continue fluently.

Comment: How many blocking calls are there? alert and prompt? Render blocking means something else, it means that parsing any JavaScript code prevents the HTML from being rendered, and you should load JavaScript after the HTML loads so it can render the HTML before requesting the JavaScript files.